# Excel - fill in cell basd on cells enters on worksheet but only fill

Tags: excel, vba, formulas

I have an excel sheet that has a sheet that our sales team have to fill in. There are 31 rows and column `d` may have the same text in multiple lines.

I need then to take all the text from column `d` and have it automatically sum the total from each text in `d`.

Column `d` is a dropdown list.

I don't want it to automatically go line from line, for example,
the data entered is:

```
9/12/15   ABC Store   $10.00
9/13/15   DEF Store   $15.00
9/14/15   ABC Store   $5.00
9/16/15   DEF Store   $50.00
```

I need it to automatically, as they enter the data to do the following on a different sheet.

```
A1= ABC Store  B1= $15.00
A2= DEF Store  B2= $65.00
```

etc. The data they choose as the enter may vary per month so I need it to understand to pick what is entered and then combine those totals if that text is choose between rows `5:31`.

I really appreciate anyone's help.

Comment: Is column D the column with the currencies? I am not sure what you mean. It looks like `SUMIF` could be your solution? Do the stores vary regularly? In case they do not: On second sheet cell B1 enter `=SUMIF(Sheet1.RangeWithStores;Sheet2.Shop;Sheet1.RangeWithCurrencies)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `=SUMIF()`-formula. See example below.

[image: SUMIF]